# iOS memory constantly increasing in app seemingly for no reason

Tags: ios, memory

This is the entry view controller for my app.

It starts out using about 6.5mb of memory and then continuously climbs for ever at a rate of about 0.1mb a second.

What on earth an I doing wrong?

There is no reason as far as I can see for any of this code to be continuously leaking, especially as it is all run once each time.

Moreover, deleting most of it doesn't seem to help. Ideas?

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Paddle Jumper
//
//  Created by Chance Daniel on 1/18/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Max Hudson. All rights reserved.
//

//#import "Flurry.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
//#import "startViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController{
    BOOL sceneSetUp;
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    if(!sceneSetUp){

        [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

        // Configure the view
        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        //skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if([[defaults objectForKey:@"firstTime"] intValue] != 1){
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"firstTime"];

            [defaults setObject:@"ggr" forKey:@"skinSelected"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"ggrOwned"];

            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100] forKey:@"gona"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1350] forKey:@"points"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7] forKey:@"livesLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"shieldsLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"lvlTwoLeftValue"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"lvlThreeLeftValue"];
        }

        if(![defaults objectForKey:@"tut_game1"]){
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_game1"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_store"];
            [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"tut_daily"];
        }

        [defaults synchronize];

        // Create and configure the scene.
        //SKScene * startScene = [StartViewController sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        //startScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        //[skView presentScene:startScene];
        //[skView presentScene:scene];

        sceneSetUp = YES;
    }

}

-(void) switchScene{

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

[image: Instruments]

Comment: Use the 'mark heap' feature of the Instruments allocation tool to help you identify what the new memory usage is.

Comment: could you help me figure out how to use it? Do I use instruments with memory leak?

Comment: it says there are 20k leaked nszombie_nsarrays and 250k leaked cgpaths

Comment: There are also 14k allocated cfstrings

Comment: I believe so but am not positive

Comment: In the toolbar of Instruments, there is a three-segment button labeled 'View'. Enable the rightmost segment and you will be able to see stack traces to the allocations when you select an allocation in the list.

Comment: Done but I'm not sure how to use it. See update post

Comment: Have you enabled NSZombies?

Comment: Yes that was the problem @HAS thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have turned on zombies. Causing leaks is exactly what zombies do! ("What zombies does" seems wrong somehow...) Its entire purpose is to prevent objects from being released. You should never check memory usage when zombies are (is?) turned on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't realize that! And I think is would be the correct choice haha

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions,

1. Try replacing

   ```
   SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
   ```

   with

   ```
   __weak SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
   ```
2. Keep the following code outside of the `if` condition.

   ```
   [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
   ```

Comment: Neither suggestion did anything unfortunately.

Comment: The first one is even quite dangerous ;) you should never call a method on a weak object pointer (always compile with `-Weverything`). The second is actually correct. You should always call the super implementation of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and not just if a condition is true.

Comment: By default an objective C variable is strong. So if self.view is simply assigned to a strong variable it will be retained ? Also self.view already have a retain count inside 'self' itself, then do we need to retain it again by assigning to a strong variable ? I thought weak referencing to self.view is enough rather than keeping strong reference, and it was causing the continuos increase of memory usage.