# Where is my AVFoundation/AVCaptureSession leaking memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, avfoundation

I'm using `AVCaptureSession` to 'record' audio and video, and using `AVAssetWriter` to actually *record* it. When my viewController loads, the view displays the 'live-feed' from the camera, but not yet recording (storing to disk). Yet, the memory-use gradually rises, and won't stop. I used `Instruments` and tried to find a leak, but I'm not sure how to interpret this. The row `VM:Allocation 16,00 KB` kept increasing, and I'm not sure what it is.

[image: Leak?]

My implementation of the delegate-method is almost doing nothing at this point:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:
(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);

    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
    CFRetain(formatDescription);

    dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{

        //If recording
        if(assetWriter){
            //do stuff
        }
    });

    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    CFRelease(formatDescription);
}
```

The problem is; when loading the view (before starting to record), the assetWriter is always nil, as it should be. So each time the above delegate-method is called, it shouldn't really do anything.
I've never done much releasing of anything, as ARC has always solved that for me. Am I doing something wrong with the `CF`-things?

Is my method somehow storing one of these variables each time?

Comment: What's your reason for those CFRetains? That's a very odd thing to do.

Comment: @matt They have no real effect though given the `dispatch_async()` in between.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm totally with you but it's still utterly unnecessary and it would be nice to know what happens with the CFRetain / CFRelease pairs all deleted.

Comment: @matt I have followed tutorials and sample codes from various authors. If I recall correctly, the CFRetain/Release is from Apple's `Rosy Writer`. I just thought they were there to prevent the other async-thread to lose track of the pointers or something weird like that. Anyway, I have removed everything inside the `didOutputSampleBuffer`-method and I still get this leak. So obviously something else is causing this. I will try to localize the leak further and update the question when I find something.

Comment: @trojanfoe and @matt, yes, the `CFRelease`s were supposed to be inside the `dispatch_async`, that was just an error from my side when typing the question. I fixed the problem, it wasn't related to this at all (see answer), but the CFRetain and Release do serve a purpose, because when I remove them, the app crashes when starting to record. Inside the async, I call another method with sampleBuffer as argument. Without the async, the samplebuffer could possibly be removed/replaced before the async could finish, I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317374/ios-memory-constantly-increasing-in-app-seemingly-for-no-reason

Comment: @matt Since the application leaked memory exclusively after starting my `AVCaptureSession`, of course I drew the conclusion that the problem was there. I searched for answers to the problem I thought I had, and found nothing. At the time, I had no reason to search for 'memory leak for no reason'. It's easy for you to search for the answer now when I've already found it. Sure, I could probably have expanded my query and spent more hours looking through unrelated topics before posting here, but I still find your last comment uncalled-for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

Earlier in the development I turned on `Enable Zombie Objects` to better debug a strange exception I experienced. Apparently, this setting **creates** zombies, or perhaps prevented ARC from releasing certain objects or whatever. By disabling this option through `Product->Edit Scheme->Enable Zombie Objects`, it works as expected, without a leak.